rank of $\mathcal{O}_K$ the ring of algebraic integers as free $\mathbb{Z}$-module
I am reviewing the content of $\mathcal{O}_K$ the ring of algebraic integers. In the proof of that $\mathrm{rank}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathcal{O}_K)=\mathrm{rank}_{\mathbb{Q}}(K)$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules and $\mathbb{Q}$-modules, the authors say that:

Since $K$ has dimension $n$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, it follows that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank at most $n$ (by Theorem 5 of Section 12.1).

But Theorem5 in Section12.1 is just the invariant factor decomposition over PIDs, which just shows that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module.
Let $R:=\mathbb{Z},D:=\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ and that $M:=\mathcal{O}_K$ as an $R$-module, then localizing $M$ at $D$ gives the $D^{-1}R=\mathrm{Frac}(R)=\mathbb{Q}$-module $D^{-1}M$, which is easily to check that $D^{-1}M=\mathrm{Frac}(\mathcal{\mathcal{O}}_K)$. But I have no ideas about how to prove that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is of free rank at most $n=\dim_{\mathbb{Q}}K$ over $\mathbb{Z}$.

If you already know that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is finitely generated over $\mathbb{Z}$, then it is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module of finite type without torsion so it is free of finite rank. Then if $a_1,\ldots,a_m$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-free in $\mathcal{O}_K$ then it is $\mathbb{Q}$-free in  $K$

@AAAL Yes, I have already know it its Noetherian and free, and your last statement is what I am confused about, I do not know how can I get it...

If not free over $\Bbb Q$, say $\sum c_j a_j = 0$ for $c_j \in \Bbb Q$, then clearing the denominators [i.e. write $c_j =m_j/n_j, m_j, n_j \in \Bbb Z, n_j \neq 0$, then multiply the equation by $\mathrm {lcm}(n_1, \dots, n_m)$ on the both sides] yields $\sum d_j a_j = 0$ for $d_j \in \Bbb Z$, then all $d_j $ hence all $c_j $ equal $0$ since $a_j$ are free over $\Bbb Z$

@xbh Thanks, I know this, what confuses me is "$\mathcal{O}_K$ is of free rank at most $n$ over $\mathbb{Z}$", the upper bound of the rank of $\mathcal{O}_K$ over $\mathbb{Z}$. I do not know how to conclude this by "$K$ is of free rank $n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$". Can you give me some help about this?

Provided that $\mathcal O_K$ is free as $\Bbb Z$-module of finite rank. Then say for any $m \geqslant n+1$ generators $(a_j)_1^m$ of $\mathcal O_K$ over $\mathbb Z$, if they are free over $\Bbb Z$ then the same procedure says thay $(a_j)1^m$ is $Q$-linearly independent, thus $n = \dim{\Bbb Q} K \geqslant m \geqslant n+1$ which is impossible.

@xbh I get it, thanks!
